# How to do customer validation with limited budget?

Tags: validation, customer

User experience designers should always go out and talk to their customers before the product is even built. But how would I do this if I had limited resources?

Most of the research I've done requires giving people some type of incentive (money) either in focus groups of interviews.

Are there any ways to do customer validation without spending any money? Also, how would I do it?

Comment: when you say customer validation, what exactly do you mean? Do you want to check if a concept will work by just a questionaire or a survay. or do you have a static prototype or mockup that you want to show and get feedback? how many users do you want to test?

Comment: [This book](http://www.leanresearch.co/) aims to answer this question exactly :).

Answer (score 1):

You can always test with some work colleagues who are not familiar with the project. In general it will work better with people who are new than people people who have been there for long (their expectations will be biased because they will be influenced by their knowledge of the company's internal organization, etc.)

Never ideal to test with colleagues, but always better than not testing at all.